# Is there any way to use COUNT variable in having clause when direct count is not possible in long multi table query

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been getting this logical error, I need to get rows that have count data more than 0. I have tried

> 'HAVING c>0'

but it return as error

> 'ORA-00904: "C": invalid identifier'

Following is the query i have been trying to give me results.

```
SELECT ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NO,(Select count(*) as cc from SALE where sale.account_no=accounts.account_no and DATED >= add_months(sysdate, -6) ) as c, (select LISTAGG(v.TYPE_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.TYPE_NAME) AS deals  from  DEALSIN v  where account_no=accounts.account_no ) as deals FROM ACCOUNTS,DETAIL_ACCOUNTS,CITY WHERE ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NO = DETAIL_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NO AND DETAIL_ACCOUNTS.CITY = REGISTRATION_NO AND PARENT_CODE = 111 AND STATUS = 'A' AND CITY =:CITY_Name having c>0 order by c desc
```

I want output as

```
ACCOUNT_NO  C   DEALS
1           10  deal1,deal2
2           9   deal1,deal3
3           3   deal4
```

but what I am getting is

```
ACCOUNT_NO  C   DEALS
1           10  deal1,deal2
2           9   deal1,deal3
3           3   deal4
4           0   deal  ----> DON'T WANT THIS ROW
5           0   deal0 ----> DON'T WANT THIS ROW
```

I dont want this row with count=0.

Comment: Rewrite the query using explicit joins instead of using correlated subqueries.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to write explicit joins. I have been using this query in my project.

Comment: Please post some sample data and related needed result, so that we can try some code and give you the right answer. Otherwise, it's hard to exactly understand your need and help you

Comment: I have quoted expected data and the data i have been getting without using `HAVING` clause. I want to compare the COUNT value in having or where clause so that these values with c=0 don't show up in resulted table.

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle specifically, but in other implementations that I know you could achieve what you want by wrapping the query in another, along the lines of: `select * from (<your original query>) where c > 0`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , Thankyou for this answer, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest rephrasing your query to do away with those inlined correlated subqueries in the select clause.  Instead, left join to separate subqueries on the `SALE` and `DEALSIN` tables.

```
SELECT
    a.ACCOUNT_NO,
    COALESCE(s.cc, 0) AS c,
    COALESCE(v.deals, 'NA') AS deals,
FROM ACCOUNTS a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT account_no, COUNT(*) AS cc
    FROM SALE
    WHERE DATED >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)
    GROUP BY account_no
) s
    ON s.account_no = a.account_no
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT account_no,
        LISTAGG(v.TYPE_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.TYPE_NAME) AS deals
    FROM DEALSIN
    GROUP BY account_no
) v
    ON v.account_no = a.account_no
INNER JOIN DETAIL_ACCOUNTS da
    ON a.ACCOUNT_NO = da.ACCOUNT_NO
INNER JOIN CITY c
    ON da.CITY = c.REGISTRATION_NO
WHERE
    PARENT_CODE = 111 AND
    STATUS = 'A' AND
    CITY =:CITY_Name AND
    COALESCE(s.cc, 0) > 0   -- your previous HAVING clause now appears in WHERE
ORDER BY
    c DESC;
```